# Addition whithin Parameters Transactional Cypher

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

Here is my problem: I want to add a integer to a property (which is of course a number) of a relationship, using Transactional Cypher.

With SET, I manage to change the property as a parameter ; but I can not add a integer to this value.

When I wrote :

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit {
  "statements": [
{ 
  "statement": "MATCH (r:CONCEPT { EX : {Example}})-[proximity:FLIGHT]->(s:NARRATION {CARD_EX: {Example2}}) SET proximity = {prop} ;",
  "parameters": {"Example":"Example","Example2":"Example2","prop":{"PROX": +144}}    
}]
}
```

I obtain :

> Payload does not seem to be valid (JSON) data

How can I add whithin Parameters ?

Thanks in advance.

Alex

Comment: You can't. You will have to do the addition from the Cypher. So `SET proximity.PROX = proximity.PROX + {prop.PROX}`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "+" sign in `+144` is not legal in JSON. Also, that `SET` syntax does not support your desired functionality.

One workaround would be to just hardcode a portion of the `SET` clause:

```
:POST /db/data/transaction/commit {
  "statements": [{ 
    "statement": "MATCH (r:CONCEPT {EX:{Example}})-[proximity:FLIGHT]->(s:NARRATION {CARD_EX: {Example2}}) SET proximity.PROX = proximity.PROX + {val};",
    "parameters": {"Example":"Example","Example2":"Example2","val": 144}
  }]
}
```